# The CDF of an uniform distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am given the uniform distribution over the interval [0,$\frac{\pi}{2}$)

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{2}{\pi} & 0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2} \\
      0 & else
   \end{cases}$$

From this function I have to find the CDF of the random variable $Y=\tan(X)$, my first steps are as follow:

$$F_y(a)=P(Y\leq a)=P(\tan(X)\leq a)=P(X\leq \arctan(a))=\int_{-\infty}^{\arctan(a)} f(x) \,dx$$

Knowing that for any $x<0$ my distribution will be zero I tried splitting  my integral,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\arctan(a)} f(x) \,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x) \,dx+\int_{0}^{\arctan(a)} f(x) \,dx=0+\int_{0}^{\arctan(a)} f(x) \,dx=\int_{0}^{\arctan(a)} f(x) \,dx$$

However since the function $\arctan$ is bounded above by $\frac{\pi}{2}$,

$$\arctan(a)<\frac{\pi}{2}\implies\int_{0}^{\arctan(a)} f(x) \,dx = \int_{0}^{\arctan(a)} \frac{2}{\pi} \,dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\arctan(a)$$

Using this result I then tried building my piecewise CDF,

$$ F_y(a) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & \arctan(a) < 0 \implies x<0 \\
      \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\arctan(a) & \arctan(a) \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}) \implies 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}\\
      1 & \arctan(a) > \frac{\pi}{2} \implies x>\frac{\pi}{2}
   \end{cases}$$

However at that point I can not figure out boundaries that make sense ($\arctan(a)>\frac{\pi}{2}$ troubling me) and I am also facing the fact that my result is not continuous.

Comment: What boundaries? Your result for $F_{y}(a)$ is correct and in fact it is continuous. What's bothering you?

Comment: $\arctan(a) \in [0,\pi/2)$ is true for any finite $0 \leq a < \infty$, so the last case is just not needed. Everything else is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! The third case of my function made me doubt about the correctness of the result but now everything seems clear to me.